# Load local js file when not server root

Tags: javascript, html, css

So my project is hosted at localhost:8080/web, using a Wildfly 10 server.  When I load the main.css file I use the tag:

`<link href="resources/scripts/css/main.css" type="text/css">`

And it does not load (404).  I load the `script.js` file:

`<script src="resources/scripts/js/script.js"></script>`

However, the `script.js` file does not load (404).  Is there any way to load the `script.js` file without specifying the project path?

The relevant folder structure is as follows:

```
resources
    scripts
        css
            main.css
        js
            script.js
    static
        views
            index.html
```

Comment: You have to use the actual URL to the file. There isn't enough information in your question to reliably determine what that URL is.

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To always load scripts from a consistent location you can use absolute paths in your href and script tags by appending '/' to the front. Presently your script and css are trying to load from `localhost:8080/web/resources/scripts/css/main.css` when you want them from `localhost:8080/resources/scripts/css/main.css`

change `'resources/scripts/css/main.css'` to `'/resources/scripts/css/main.css'`

Comment: you have it backwards, I want to load from `localhost:8080/web/resources/scripts/css/main.css` but it is loading from `localhost:8080/resources/scripts/css/main.css`

Comment: so your html file is at `/web` and the relative path is attempting to load from root? Can you verify in the network traffic what precise URL the browser is trying to get? The browser will interpret your relative or absolute paths, so if it's attempting to load from `/` then your path is messed up.

Comment: looking back at the original question, this looks like a server setup issue rather than a general HTML/JS issue. You need to map /resources to /web/resources in your server. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with wildfly to do this, but you should target a question to that community.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way build a java war file is to make sure that your front-end is always aware that it can run under different context paths. The same project should run as http://127.0.0.1/ or http://127.0.0.1/myproject/ depending on how it is deployed.

Unfortunately, there is no super easy way to do this with HTML files.

If you convert your html to jsp you could then use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/scripts/js/script.js"></script>
```

Or for JSF2:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/scripts/js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just moved it to server root to fix the issue

Comment: Recommendations without a rationale aren't very helpful. You need to explain, what the problem is, and how your proposed solution solves it.

Comment: It's my own answer